# Bootstrap 3 - How to properly display buttons (btn-navbar) in collapsed navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I made a footer that contains 3 buttons (btn-navbar) using the following HTML code. When the navbar is collapsed I can toogle it properly, but the buttons are displayed all in the same line instead of one on top of each other like it does with `<li>` elements.

```
  <!-- Fixed navbar bottom -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-footer">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Verificar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancelar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Aceptar</button>

        </ul>

      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-footer">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

It shows like this...

[image: footer]

And I'd like it to show like this...

[image: header]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The text and icons look quite different from the buttons or is that just an interpretation?

Comment: Is there a reason you have not put the buttons inside `<li>`s?  The only permitted content of a `<ul>` is _zero or more <li> elements, eventually mixed with <ol> and <ul> elements._ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/D2RLR/6171/)**

You are missing li within ul. `HTML` markup issue:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Verificar</button></li>
   <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancelar</button></li>
   <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Aceptar</button></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: You may want to update the link. It no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each of your buttons in an li tag, like this:

```
<li><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning navbar-btn">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Verificar</button></li>
```

Each line inside of a ul tag needs to be wrapped in li tags to behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Your HTML is not correct. A `button` element cannot directly nested within a `ul` element.**

You must wrap your button element in `LI` element.

Try this HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-footer">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class = "active"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Verificar</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancelar</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancelar</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Aceptar</button>
       </ul>
    </div>

   <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-footer">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
   </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2Gsa/8/)